# Way to perform small sql query in background in c#?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I log my app's events to small file database (sqlite)
The log table has only 3 fields: id of order, message and timestamp.
Log entries show up not so frequently thus I can insert logs records just in time. But nevertheless I would like to perform query in separate thread, how I do that? I mean how not to "overreact" with that? I just not so clear about what fiber and thread is. Here's my class responsible for db Logging:

```
internal class LogEntryManager
     {
         private SQLiteConnection _sqlite;
         public LogEntryManager()
         {
             if (!File.Exists(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\logs.db"))
             {
                 SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("logs.db");
                 _sqlite = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\logs.db");
                 _sqlite.Open();
                 SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("CREATE TABLE logs (Id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, OrderId INTEGER NOT NULL, Message TEXT, Timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)", _sqlite);
                 command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 _sqlite.Close();
             }
             else
                 _sqlite = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=logs.db");
         }

         public void WriteLogEntry(int order, string message)
         {
             _sqlite.Open();  //Initiate connection to the db
             SQLiteCommand cmd = _sqlite.CreateCommand();
             cmd.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO logs (OrderId, Message) VALUES ({0}, {1});", order, message);
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             _sqlite.Close();
         }
     }
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) queue for robust background tasks handling.